# Visual C++ Project System Package

Tags: visual-studio-2017

The 'Visual C++ Project System Package' package did not load correctly.

The problem may have been caused by a configuration change or by the installation of another extension. You can get more information by examining the file 
'C:\Users\Armyw0w\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_7c22efff\ActivityLog.xml'.

Restarting visual Studio could help resolve this issue.

Continue to show this error message?

that file log: https://pastebin.com/sA9yDiKr

```
<description>LegacySitePackage failed for package [Visual C++ Project System Package]Source: &apos;Microsoft.VisualStudio.Project.VisualC.VCProjectEngine&apos; Description: No platforms have been found on this installation.&#x000D;&#x000A;System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x8005050A): No platforms have been found on this installation.&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Project.VisualC.VCProjectEngine.VCProjectEngineShim.&lt;ReadInstalledPlatformsAsync&gt;d__264.MoveNext()&#x000D;&#x000A;--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Project.VisualC.VCProjectEngine.VCProjectEngineShim.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass55_0.&lt;&lt;Initialize&gt;b__0&gt;d.MoveNext()&#x000D;&#x000A;--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Project.VisualC.VCProjectEngine.ApartmentMarshaler.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass7_0.&lt;&lt;Invoke&gt;b__0&gt;d.MoveNext()&#x000D;&#x000A;--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.JoinableTask.CompleteOnCurrentThread()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Project.VisualC.VCProjectEngine.ApartmentMarshaler.Invoke(Func`1 method)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Project.VisualC.VCProjectEngine.VCProjectEngineShim.Initialize(IntPtr instResources, Object sp, Object browser, IVCBuildPackageInternal bldPkg)</description>
```

somebody know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Your Visual Studio might be missing a "workload" that installs an add-on extension needed for your package.

I was having this same issue and uninstalled and reinstalled Visual Studio and deleted all remnants of Visual Studio before reinstalling.   Then when the issue was there again, I dove in to similar questions online like 
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d89adaf1-0548-4c8f-b1b9-aee0a1140c91/visual-studio-2017-package-load-problem
.  Other people getting this issue on earlier versions of Visual Studio noted that the project type guid tells VS what it needs to load the package.  My guid did not match any project type guids online.  Then I learned Visual Studio 2017 automatically generates unique guids per project and does not set a published ID anymore like earlier versions.

Then I looked more in this file about Project Type and realized it was building a Win32 application.  I scanned the workloads in Visual Studio Installer for a Windows application and downloaded the .NET for Windows app workload.  I was still getting the issue after restarting my computer and found that I had to delete the .vs folder for my project for Visual Studio to "reset" itself.  I deleted the .vs folder and it finally as able to load my package.